# Existence of periodic solutions for the system: $x'=x^2+y^2+1$, $y'=x^2-y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> Determine whether the following nonlinear system has periodic solutions.
>
> \begin{align}
> x'&=x^2+y^2+1\\
> y'&=x^2-y^2
> \end{align}

I have tried using polar coordinates but it just becomes complicated and doesn't give any information. I've also tried the candidate Lyapunov function

$$V(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)$$

but, since $\dot{V}$ is not negative definite, I can't apply Poincaré-Bendixson theorem since I can't find a positively invariant set.

I have also tried to show that there can be no orbits by using Bendixson's criterion, but the divergence is not $\neq 0$ thus the result is inconclusive. Any idea how to approach this?

Comment: Note that $x'\geq 1$ for all $(x,y)$.

Answer (score 2):

As highlighted in the previous comment, since $1\leq\dot{x}(t)$ it comes out easily that the orbits cannot be closed and hence be periodic, otherwise there would be a certain time interval where the x decreases.